# Apex item with embedded html as value

Tags: html, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to make easy form filling for users, which is why I have difficulties with default apex items. I need to make slightly complex html element, because Radio Group is not good enough, since there need to be some additional fill in, depending on which option you select. For example i have this picture of what I was trying to achieve:

[image]

In other words i need radio button element with 2 input elements inside string. I tried to render html input inside my SQL source:

```
SELECT 'some random string' || ' <input></input> ' || 'and some more string' || '<input></input>'
FROM DUAL
```

But this doesn't work since I only get errors. I couldn't find any hints on this searching the web, and I believe apex do support custom elements. Managed only to add input box at the end of the 3rd string by putting  tag into items Post Text property.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
You should have a PL/SQL Dynamic content region in your page with the source:

```
DECLARE
V_TEXT VARCHAR2(5000) := 'some random string' || ' <input></input> ' || 'and some more string' || '<input></input>';
BEGIN
htp.p(v_text);
END;
```

[image]
Then you would have the HTML rendered.

Comment: I was trying to put htp functions but inside apex Items source, and that is where I messed up. Because now I see that html renderer is only accessible on the apex Regions. Thanks a lot Cengiz.

Comment: yeah, normally, in the help section of the page items & regions there are examples but for the pl/sql dynamic content, there is no examples. So you need to figure out yourself how to shape the source of this type of regions. I'm glad that it helped you.